# how to solve this Error from using in_array

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have this team  page that contains a list of team  members and a select list that contains the list of my friends. From the select list, you can select friends to be added to the team (members). Now, I want to ensure that friends that are already team members don't show up in the select list.

I tried the below but nothing is showing in the select list, it is supposed to show the details of one friend who is not part of the team members.

The code

```
    <form action="tmembers.php" method="post">
             <select multiple="true" name="members[]"  val id="member" class="">


        <?php
            while($record5 = $stmt5->fetch()){ //Gets ids from my friend list
            $friends[] = $record5['id'];      //array containing ids of friends
            }
         $membersarray[] = $members['id'];  //array containing ids of team members


         foreach ($friends AS $t) {
        if (in_array($t, $membersarray)) {
            continue;            
        } 
     ?>


    <option value="<?php echo $record5['id'] ; ?>">  <?php echo $record5['surname'];?> <?php echo $record5['firstname'] ; ?>  </option>
<?php }
  ?>


</select></br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send Invite" name="invite" class=""/>
 </form>
```

Comment: have you tried var_dumping the arrays to check they are o.k. first ?

Comment: Why would you just not do this all in the query?

Comment: @prodigitalson, how do you mean?

Comment: Like only select friends for the list not already assigned to the team in question like: `SELECT * FROM friend_list f WHERE f.user_id = ? AND f.friend_id NOT IN (SELECT t.id FROM team_members t WHERE t.team_id <> ?)` Not sure if thats an accurate assumption of your table structure but I would think it would look somehting like that.

Comment: Show us your SQL. You can use something like `... WHERE id NOT IN (...)`. Inside the parentheses you need a comma separated list of member ids.

Comment: Good point prodigitalson, something like `SELECT friends FROM memberstable
UNION
SELECT friends FROM teamTable` should only give unique results of people that don't appear on both

Comment: I get the  ids for friends using this:                         $sql5 = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM addclique i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.clique_id WHERE adder_id = :id";                                     $stmt5 = $db->query($sql5, array('id' => $_SESSION['id']));          $record5 = $stmt5->fetch()

Comment: I get the get the ids for members using this: $team = "SELECT i.*, m.* FROM tmembers i JOIN members m ON m.id = i.members WHERE team_id = :id";
              
               foreach ($db->query($team, array('id' => $_GET['id'])) AS $output)
               {   $op = $output['id'];
               }
               ?>